# Property bindings not working as expected with ListView + Delegate (nested items)

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am writing a simple candlestick chart program in QML. Data is modeled as a list. Elements are plotted one after another regardless of timestamp differences (i.e. no gaps on the x axis). This is intentional.
This simple model works as expected with below example code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
// dimensions arbitrary
    height: 1000
    width: 400
    property int bar_spacing: 1
// example dimensions of the y axis, axis omitted for simplicity
// used to position candlesticks vertically
    property real y_axis_px_per_unit: 720/360
    property real y_axis_max:    660
    property int bar_min_width: 10

    Component {
        id: candlestickItem
        Candlestick {
            ts:    model.ts
            open:  model.open
            high:  model.high
            low:   model.low
            close: model.close
            px_per_unit: y_axis_px_per_unit
            axis_max:    y_axis_max
            min_width: bar_min_width
// each candlestick scaled to fill listview, min_width is 
// the scaling limit (if the candle_width calculation 
// results in smaller candles than min_width, then 
// min_width is used and listview has a horizontal scrollbar)
            candle_width: {
                // Total width - spaces between elements - left margin
                (candles_view.implicitWidth - candles_view.count * candles_view.spacing - candles_view.spacing) / candles_view.count
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: candles_view
        model: ticks
        delegate: candlestickItem

        implicitHeight: parent.height
        implicitWidth: parent.width
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.leftMargin: bar_spacing

        clip: true

        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        layoutDirection: "LeftToRight"
        spacing: bar_spacing
    }

    ListModel {
        id: ticks
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-01 00:00:00'; open: 608.4900; high: 615.0000; low: 515.0000; close: 519.0000; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-02 00:00:00'; open: 631.2650; high: 653.6500; low: 553.0000; close: 631.2732; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-03 00:00:00'; open: 562.0000; high: 608.0000; low: 508.0000; close: 534.0000; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-04 00:00:00'; open: 506.5000; high: 505.0100; low: 405.0000; close: 453.0001; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-05 00:00:00'; open: 472.0000; high: 484.0000; low: 384.0000; close: 407.5601; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-06 00:00:00'; open: 403.0000; high: 404.8600; low: 304.0000; close: 373.0000; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-07 00:00:00'; open: 365.0000; high: 451.9900; low: 351.0000; close: 394.0000; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-08 00:00:00'; open: 447.9500; high: 477.0000; low: 377.0000; close: 423.7800; }
    }
}
```

Which produces a very basic, but correct chart:
[image: basic, working chart]

I would like to extend this by placing the candlestick within another item, a "container" (not in QML sense), which could contain other items as well, such as lines plotted over the candle, histograms etc. However, when I create a new QML item, the chart does not work anymore:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    height: 1000
    width: 400
    property int bar_spacing: 1
    property real y_axis_px_per_unit: 720/360
    property real y_axis_max:    660
    property int bar_min_width: 10

    Component {
        id: chartItemDelegate

        ChartItem {
            model: model
            count: candles_view.count
            spacing: bar_spacing
            view_width: candles_view.implicitWidth
            y_axis_max: y_axis_max
            y_axis_px_per_unit: y_axis_px_per_unit
            bar_min_width: bar_min_width
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: candles_view
        model: ticks
        delegate: chartItemDelegate

        implicitHeight: parent.height
        implicitWidth: parent.width
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.leftMargin: bar_spacing

        clip: true

        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        layoutDirection: "LeftToRight"
        spacing: bar_spacing
    }

    ListModel {
        id: ticks
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-01 00:00:00'; open: 608.4900; high: 615.0000; low: 515.0000; close: 519.0000; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-02 00:00:00'; open: 631.2650; high: 653.6500; low: 553.0000; close: 631.2732; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-03 00:00:00'; open: 562.0000; high: 608.0000; low: 508.0000; close: 534.0000; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-04 00:00:00'; open: 506.5000; high: 505.0100; low: 405.0000; close: 453.0001; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-05 00:00:00'; open: 472.0000; high: 484.0000; low: 384.0000; close: 407.5601; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-06 00:00:00'; open: 403.0000; high: 404.8600; low: 304.0000; close: 373.0000; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-07 00:00:00'; open: 365.0000; high: 451.9900; low: 351.0000; close: 394.0000; }
        ListElement { ts: '2020-01-08 00:00:00'; open: 447.9500; high: 477.0000; low: 377.0000; close: 423.7800; }
    }
}
```

`ChartItem.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    property ListModel model
    property real y_axis_px_per_unit
    property real y_axis_max
    property int bar_min_width
    property int view_width
    property int spacing
    property int count

    id: chart_item
    implicitWidth: candlestick.implicitWidth
    implicitHeight: candlestick.implicitHeight

    Candlestick {
        id: candlestick
        ts:    model.ts
        open:  model.open
        high:  model.high
        low:   model.low
        close: model.close
        px_per_unit: y_axis_px_per_unit
        axis_max:    y_axis_max
        min_width: bar_min_width
        candle_width: {
            // Total width - spaces between elements - left margin
            (view_width - count * spacing - spacing) / count
        }
    }

}
```

The result is a window with 1 pixel-high yellow line, which implies that neither the model nor axis dimensions used to position bars were passed on to the candlestick item:

[image: broken chart example]

I've tried debugging this in QtCreator, but didn't understand why it is not working. I also tried passing each value from the model like originally with the candlestick:

```
ts:    model.ts
open:  model.open
high:  model.high
low:   model.low
close: model.close
```

But the result was the same.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. How can I pass values to ChartItem from the ListView/ListModel? As a first step, I would like to reproduce the working example with ChartItem as a container for CandlestickItem and later add more elements within ChartItem as needed
2. Passing the model via a property binding does not seem to work but passing each relevant value from the model does not work either. Is it possible to pass entire objects? For example, can I pass the entire view as a property like so: `property ListView view` and then refer to its fields: `view.model.ts`? I've tried that without success
3. Is it possible that issues presented here are related to lifetimes/times of creation of delegates and the view? If that's the case, how should I structure the code to avoid such issues?

Thank you for reading and your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was simpler than I thought.

1. Resolve property name clashes. Qualify rhs values of each binding with `model` and Item's id or use different property names altogether. I prefer being more explicit:

```
        ChartItem {
            ts:    model.ts
            open:  model.open
            high:  model.high
            low:   model.low
            close: model.close

            view: candles_view
            y_axis_max: y_axis_max
            y_axis_px_per_unit: y_axis_px_per_unit
            bar_min_width: bar_min_width
        }
```

`ChartItem.qml`

```
Candlestick {
        id: candlestick
        ts:    chart_item.ts
        open:  chart_item.open
        high:  chart_item.high
        low:   chart_item.low
        close: chart_item.close
        ...
    }
```

2. Yes and no. Yes, if it is an object. Works with `view`, because it is an object.

Define property:

```
property ListView view
```

Bind a value when an Item is created:

```
view: candles_view
```

Use in the item:

```
candle_width:
        {
            // Total width - spaces between elements - left margin
            (view.implicitWidth - view.count * view.spacing - view.spacing) / view.count
        }
```

It didn't work with `model`. My understanding is that model has a special meaning and is not meant to be used this way, but would love to be proven wrong.

3. Nope

Comment: you have gone with `model: some_id.model` or `myModel: model` since `model` is found in the scope of `ChartItem` it will be referencing it's own property.

Comment: @Amfasis if I understand what you said correctly, then passing a model object should work just fine, I just need to make sure to avoid property name shadowing just like with other properties. Correct?

Comment: yes indeed (I see I missed 'could' as the second word in my previous comment ;-) )